# Missing reference for Chart even with System.Web.Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, charts

I'm going a little bit nuts over here.. I'm just trying to make a simple chart, but I can't find the reference.

Everyone says to add "System.Web.Helpers", i even added another System.Web.Helpers 2.0 as a reference and I can't get Chart to find the reference.. under System.Web.Helpers. i only see:

- AntiForgery
- AntiForgeryConfig
- AntiXsrf Claims
- IantiForgeryAddtioonalDataProvider
- UnvalidatedRequestValues
- Validation

thanks for any help.  i'm using asp.net mvc 4

Comment: So just to be sure, you tried adding a Chart object, and it didn't recognize the class?

Comment: yes it says am i missing a directive or assembly reference

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in Visual Studio at the moment so when investigating my local Object Browser, I see my System.Web.Helpers is referencing a Nuget Package - [(Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/) which does include the Chart class. The project I am currently in appears to be Target Framework of 4.5, but Chart still appeared to be present when switching to version 4.

Comment: hm adding a reference to that messed up my whole project for some reason... had to revert it back through my repo.. bleh i give up.,  gonna go the javascript route i guess.  than you for your help appreciate it